# preg_replace not working the way I need it to

Tags: php, search, preg-replace, file-get-contents

The following is not working the way I need it to work:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('www.site.com'); 
$var1= preg_replace('#ProdSupp\*(.*?)\*ProdSupp#siu', '$1', $homepage);
```

when it file contents the site it DOES find the stuff inside `ProdSupp* *ProdSupp`, but var1 stores the ENTIRE content after it fetches the string its looking for....how can I eliminate EVERYTHING in var1 and ONLY make it store the stuff between `ProdSupp* *ProdSupp`?

I dont know how to eliminate the junk text and only store the value between `ProdSupp* *ProdSupp`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at `preg_match` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"[My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com/)" (it's not mine, it's just what it's called) is a handy tool for debugging stuff like this.  If I read what you're trying to do correctly, it seems like you should actually be using `preg_match_all()` instead of `preg_replace()`.

```
<?php
$sourcestring = "ProdSupp*baz 12345 foo bar*ProdSupp";
preg_match_all('/ProdSupp\*(.*?)\*ProdSupp/ims', $sourcestring, $matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true)."</pre>";
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ProdSupp*baz 12345 foo bar*ProdSupp
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => baz 12345 foo bar
        )
)
```

So when all is said and done, the contents you're looking for are in `$matches[1][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

As was already mentioned, you should probably used some kind of preg_match function, if I understood your question correctly.

If you would like to both make replacements and get matches, you could use preg_replace_callback with global variable like this:

```
<?php
global $var1;
$var1= array();

global $index;
$index=0;


$callbackFunction = create_function('$matches',  
   ' 
     global $var1;
     global $index; 
     $var1[$index]=$matches[1];
     $index++;
     return $matches[1]; 
   ');

   $var11= preg_replace_callback('#ProdSupp\*(.*?)\*ProdSupp#siu', $callbackFunction, $homepage); 

?>
```

In $var1 array will be your matches inside brackets and in $var11 the whole modified content.